# Email notification when cell value is <=7 or >=7

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets, notifications, cell

I need help trying to make this script work. I want to get daily email notifications if column Y3:Y is less than or equal to 7 OR Y3:Y is greater than or equal to 0. I want it to return information from column Q specific to that row.

So far, I have:

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "x@email.com";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('Y')<=7){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('Q'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Order is due soon for'+sheet.getName();
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' order is due soon. Click ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to see which PO is due, look at row # to see details: «' + row + '». PO#: «' + cellvalue;
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

I have this for my trigger.

[image: trigger]

Here is the sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HUaW1ZowU1ss1_JInLuML7jeVffDwZ5pl-EujooBJU4/edit?usp=sharing

I have a feeling my trigger is incorrect. Sorry in advance, still new to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is closer to what you want

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "x@email.com";
  const vs = sh.getRange("A3:Y" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
  const name = sh.getName();
  const url = ss.getUrl();
  let rows = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (r[24] > -1 && r[24] < 8) {
      rows.push(r);//save array of all rows
      let message = r[16];
      let row = i + 3;//added row number
      let subject = 'Order is due soon for' + name;
      var body = name + ' order is due soon. Click ' + url + ' to see which PO is due, look at row # to see details: «' + row + '». PO#: «' + cellvalue;
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
    }
  })
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rows));
}
```

Comment: I did it and it worked. It changed the timer, but now I'm having some more trouble. How do I get it to retrieve all the rows that have the value <=7.

Comment: I collected all of the rows in rows.

Comment: I get:

JFC order is due soon. Click 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B8jxk08l-ICr8Y0ZZ7VbpQkQ0YeajyRA3k0zB0d7PBU/edit 
to see which PO is due, look at row # to see details: «1». PO#: «

Comment: Access to Spreadsheet is no longer public